# Shell command not found

Tags: bash

I made a bash script file and saved it in my home directory. When I run it I get the following output:

```
sudo:not found
mount:not found
```

However `set -e` gives no errors.

There are no other commands in my file.

It is a .sh file and its contents are:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
sudo mount vboxsf folder ~/shared
```

where 'folder' is the folder to be mounted in shared
I run it by double clicking as it is a executable script

Comment: what command are you using to run it and is it a .sh script? Please edit your question because it's not clear

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste your complete script and how exactly you run it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try yr script as:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
sudo mount -t vboxsf folder ~/shared
```

Do not forget the `-t` mount flag, to signal that you're mounting a virtual box shared folder.
Careful too with what you mount where. If yr shared folder is called `folder` in above script and you mount it at `~/shared`, then you're ok ...